# Import csv using dataflow-profile image does not exists?

Tags: magento-1.8, import, image

I am using Magento version is 1.8.1.0.

I am trying to import product using dataflow - profile. when I run the I got error image does not exists.

I place image into `media/import/product/p1.jpg`

my media folder permission is 777.

and I write image path into `csv` file like.

```
image               small_image          thumbnail
/product/p1.jpg   /product/p1.jpg    /product/p1.jpg
```

where I create mistake please help.

when I upload this csv and run i got this error.

```
Image does not exist.
```

Comment: I faced the same issue. Then the problem was .jpg extension. I went to the properties of .jpg image, But there I could see the extension of the image was .jpeg. (So go to the properties of image and fine the correct extension(.jpg or .jpeg))

Comment: Sometimes i had this problem because the text was not saved in UTF-8 Encoding. From Sublime Text i just did File > Save with encoding > UTF-8. Hope this helps.

Comment: i used magmi for import product and it is very easy to used and very powerfull library.   http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/

Answer (score 9):

Place the image under `media/import` then in the CSV use `/p1.jpg` - there is no need for the extra `/product` sub-directory.

Answer (score 0):

here the issue is product folder.
place the product folder inside the media/import only.

i,e media/import/product/p1.jpg